# What is the meaning of spherical dataset?

Tags: classification, dataset, k-means, unsupervised-learning

In the following [article](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12859-017-1578-z), one of the statement is as follows:

> The K-means algorithm is effective only for spherical datasets

What does spherical dataset mean?

Comment: In this context it means the clusters are spherical in shape.

Comment: Second what Emre said, k-means is (more) effective for spherical clusters, not spherical datasets.  The paper may be wrong or just not very precisely worded.  By the way: sufficiently high-dimensional datasets tends to have some surprising distance properties: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99171/why-is-euclidean-distance-not-a-good-metric-in-high-dimensions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, a picture is a worth a thousand words. They literally mean data whose distribution on X,Y is roughly a sphere. Different clustering algorithms work better on different distributions. For example, K means does poorly on the arrangement in the first two rows but OK on the last row.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**spherical dataset** is basically a form of **non-linear dataset** in which observational data are modeled by a function which is **a non-linear combination of the model parameters and depends on one or more independent variables**.

If your dataset has **high variance** , you need to reduce the number of features and add more dataset. After that you can then use **non-linear methods** for classification.

Also, Non-linear methods typically involves applying some type of transformation to your input dataset. After the transformation, many techniques can then try to use a linear method for classification.